# How to dynamically populate a menu control on a custom ribbon?

Tags: vba, excel, openxml, ribbon

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
ListBox1.AddItem ws.Name
Next ws

ListBox1_Click()
Worksheets(ListBox1.Value).Activate
```

Could I have the same thing with a menu control on a custom ribbon
xml:

```
<menu id="mnuCats" label="abc" size="large" imageMso="PropertySheet"  >
<button id="go01" label="sky"  onAction="go01" imageMso="TextAlignGallery" />
<button id="go02" label="sea"  onAction="go02" imageMso="TextAlignGallery" />
</menu>
```

So, how to populate the menu with sheet names and how to get label attribute of a button as a string, for activating corresponding sheet.

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/439475-dynamic-ribbon-control-custom-ui-resources.html shows how to populate a drop-down on the ribbon. It's considerably more complex than your listbox example though.

Comment: @ThankYou Tim, I will try. Btw, what should I type here to get "@" sign with a marked name. I tried with tab and enter - doesn''t work.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a dropdown ribbon control. If you enter the following customUI XML in your Excel file (maybe by using the Custom UI Editor http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2006/05/25/customuieditor.aspx) you can get a list of the correct VBA callback signatures you need to implement in order to fill the values and respond to actions:

```
<dropDown id="drpTest" label="Test" showImage="false" getSelectedItemIndex="TestGetSelItem" onAction="TestOnAction" getItemCount="TestGetItemCount" getItemID="TestGetItemID" getItemLabel="TestGetItemLabel" sizeString="HowBigDropdownDoYouWant" supertip="Select Test.">
</dropDown>
```